# An equivalent definition of valuation rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, valuation-theory

I got stuck at the following exercise:

> Let $V$ be an (unitary) integral domain contained in a field $K$. Then $V$ is a
> valuation ring with quotient field $K$ if and only if for every $u \in K$ either $u \in V$ or
> $u^{-1} \in V$.

Here is the definition of valuation ring that I know:

> Definition: A commutative ring $V$ is called **valuation ring** if for all $a, b \in V$ holds **either** $a \mid b$ or $b \mid a$.

Here is what I got so far:

$\Longrightarrow$: Assume that for an $u \in K$ holds both $u \in V$ and $u^{-1} \in V$. Since $1 = u u^{-1}$ this implies that $u \mid 1$. But this is a contradiction to our assumption that $V$ is a valuation ring, since it (trivially) also holds that $1 \mid u$.

$\Longleftarrow$: This is the direction where I got stuck. I tried a proof by contradiction, so assume for some $a,b \in V$ holds $a \mid b$ and $b \mid a$, but I do not know how to continue.

Could you give me a hint?

Comment: What if $u \in K$ with $u = u^{-1}$?

Comment: In your second definition you need to assume that $V$ is an integral domain (try with $\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}$) so it is clearly equivalent to the first definition just by letting $u = b/a$.

Comment: To expand on what @Geoff writes, it is wrong to interpret "or" as "xor" (exclusive or, either or) in these definitions. Most valuation rings have big groups of units, and every one of course contains at least a $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might like to look at the article "On Valuation Rings" which I wrote with a colleague a little time ago. You can find it on the web. RC

Comment: While your paper may contain the answer to this question, answers on math.se are supposed to be self-contained and not depend crucially on external resources whenever possible. As it stands, your answer would be better as a comment, but if you add the material from your paper that answers the question then it would constitute an answer.